# Performance: Better low end of eight string guitar

Tags: guitar

I'm wondering how to get better, clearer low end tone from an active-pickup eight-string guitar? It's being played through a Vox AC30, used specifically for clean and layered loops in an ambient project. How would an equalizer or compressor help?

Comment: Have you tried playing it through a bass amp to see if the guitar itself is producing the sound you need at the low end?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you'll need to look at here:

First - the amplifier.

A normal guitar amp (such as an AC30) is really only designed to work well in the frequency range of a guitar tuned from E to E. If your guitar is tuned similarly, you are adding a G and B below that low E - the amp is not going to faithfully recreate these.

So you'll need to look at an amp with a wider frequency range (or use an amp and a bass amp...) and ensure your speaker cabinet can cope with the lower range (there is a reason bass cabs are big!)

Secondly - the guitar

Choice of low string gauge can make a great difference in both playability and sound. Thicker strings usually give a greater volume through the pickups, but may not sound as clear on a normal guitar scale length.
Tone controls are generally basic - filtering treble is generally how they work - so using a graphic equaliser to boost a bit of the low end plus a bit of the top end can make the bass notes sound clearer.